# Close file descriptor (in user-space) when UIO driver is unregistered (in kernel)

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-panic

In an embedded system running Linux, we have a PCI driver in user-space making use of the kernel driver for UIO. The application can trigger registration of the device which calls `__uio_register_device()` in the kernel's `uio.c`. Then the application opens the device file (`/dev/uio0`). And then it misbehaves by unregistering the device (`uio_unregister_device()`) which frees some kernel memory holding device information. Then the application closes the file - and the kernel panics because pointers which have been freed are being accessed.

Apart from fixing the application, how can I make the Linux kernel robust against this?

`uio_open()` and `uio_release()` get file pointers which point to the critical allocated memory (in `private_data`). But `uio_unregister_device()` doesn't have this information, so I don't know what to do. Or is there a way  to force-close the file in the application? Any other suggestions or a different interpretation of what's happening?

Edit: can be easily reproduced as follows - and shows the user-space perspective:

```
# replace '1234 abcd' by vendor id and device id
echo '1234 abcd' > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/new_id
echo '0000:00:01.0' > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/bind
# 'bind' may not even be needed. /dev/uio0 is created
cat /dev/uio0 &
# now be bad
echo '0000:00:01.0' > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/unbind
kill <cat process ID>
# kernel panic...
```

Causes a crash due to `Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address` - with three different flavors. Either `idev`, `idev->info` or `idev->owner` is an invalid pointer (not necessary NULL, just random data).

Comment: I dont know how you can do this with uio, but typically a driver module cannot be unloaded if files are open. Each open of a file would do `try_module_get()` to increment the in-use count. You would get EBUSY to `rmmod` if the count is not zero. The other scenario is with hotplug devices; when the device is removed the driver can kill(-9) any processes with open files. This avoids any oops.

Comment: Can you post a stack trace from the kernel panic?

Comment: @meuh: There is a misunderstanding - I am not talking about unloading the module (it's built-in, by the way) but about unregistering the specific device.

Comment: @murray See my edit above.